# Create an object without New?

Tags: vb.net

I noticed that one can create a `String` with or without `New`:

```
Dim s As String
```

or

```
Dim s As New String(" "c, 4)
```

The second way suggests to me that a `String` is a class instance. The first way suggests that one can create an object without using `New`. However, when I try to create an instance of my own class without `New`, I get an uninitialized reference error. What am I missing?

P.S.: I have an idea of my own: `String` is defined as a *Structure*, not a *Class*. Please confirm if this is correct.

Comment: @Plutonix - The first way doesn't define the string as empty, it's `Nothing` (or `null`).

Comment: @Enigmativity yes - I dont think I was actually awake

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim s As String
```

This does not create a new `String` object. This declares that `s` is a variable of type `String`. This is also why you get a `NullReferenceException` when you try to use that variable.

```
Dim s As New String(" "c, 4)
```

This declares the variable `s` as type `String` and initializes the variable to a certain value.

> The second way suggests to me that a String is a class instance.
>
> I have an idea of my own: String is defined as a Structure, not a Class. Please confirm if this is correct.

`String` is a class type. See the definition in the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<SerializableAttribute>
<ComVisibleAttribute(True)>
Public NotInheritable Class String
    Implements IComparable, ICloneable, IConvertible, IEnumerable,
    IComparable(Of String), IEnumerable(Of Char), IEquatable(Of String)
```

Comment: I don't think this is true. The first declaration is a definition. `s` becomes an empty string. In particular, you can do `s &= "a"` after that. The question is: how come?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - The first way is `Nothing` (or `null`), not an empty string. You can always do a concat with `Nothing`. This works fine: `Dim s As String = Nothing & "Foo"`, the result simply being `"Foo"`.

Comment: But how come I can do `Console.WriteLine(s)` after declaring `s` as `String` without `New`? I do get a warning from Visual Studio, but no exception is thrown when I run the program...

Answer (score 0):

To explain a little more simply, if you use the following code,

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim a As String
    MessageBox.Show(a)
End Sub
```

Visual studio will still give you an error on the MessageBox line:-

> > Variable 'a' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

So when it is declared in the Dim statement, you still just have an object that is a string type and has no string assigned to it.

And no a string is definitely a class.

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. What does "could result" mean? Undefined behavior?

Comment: Sorry, yes a warning not an error. If you try and get a value from the object before assigning one, you'll get a null reference exception, but if you assign a value, you won't. :)

Comment: Not really.  I can do `Console.WriteLine(s)` after declaring `s` as `String` without `New` and no exception is thrown...

Comment: Ok I chose a bad example. try Dim s As String     Dim t As Integer    t = s.Length. Null reference exception. So you're not accepting that Microsoft are telling you that a string is a class? Enough.

Comment: Please don't take me wrong. I am certainly accepting what Microsoft writes in the documentation. However, this raises questions and I want to understand what happens. So, what happens when I do `Console.WriteLine(s)`?

Comment: `Nothing` is Sent to the console